# Correct sentence

Tags: sentence-patterns

What is the correct form? It's a the title of an article

How I used my air pilot transferable skills to build a new career

Or

How I used my transferable skills as an air pilot to build a new career

Comment: The second form is correct. The first is an example of strained or awkward usage.

Comment: Neither is particularly clear and consise.

Comment: You don’t need the word transferable.